# Set `init` property of imported C struct in Swift

Tags: swift

I've imported a C struct into my Swift project, however I'm unable to get or set the `init` property on the imported struct, getting the following error:

> error: 'init' is a member of the type; use 'type(of: ...)' to initialize a new object of the same dynamic type

The original C struct is something like:

```
struct test_t {
  int init;
};
```

and my Swift code that fails looks like:

```
var t = test_t()
let i = t.init      // error thrown here
t.init = 10         // error thrown here
```

I can understand that the name is an issue, so is there some other way to set properties on structs in Swift, perhaps involving some meta programming or dynamic dispatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare variable names to use reserved keywords by using the backtick around their names like

```
struct Test {
    var `init`:Int
}
```

You can do the same with the call to an imported property/method whose name is a reserved keyword when you access/call that property/method.

```
var t = test_t()
let i = t.`init`
t.`init` = 10
```